# Jboss Messaging WorkerThread# what are these threads?

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss-messaging

I am load testing a jboss messaging install with 5 producers producing 100,000 100k messages. I am seeing significant bottlenecking. When I monitor the profiler, I see there are 15 threads named WorkerThread#. These threads are allocated 100% with no waits. I think they may be related. Does anyone know what function these threads service and if there is a threadpool setting. I am using a supp

JBoss Enterprise Application Server  4.3 CP08
JBoss Enterprise Service Bus  4.4 CP04
JBoss Transactions  4.2.3._CP07
JBoss Messaging  1.4.0.SP3-CP09
JBoss Rules  4.0.7
JBoss jBPM  3.2.9
JBoss Web Services  2.0.1.SP2_CP07

Comment: If you're producing 100,000 messages of 100k each, why are you surprised that you have several threads working at full throttle? Surely this is a good thing.

Comment: Sure am. But my hardware is not tapped in the least. This must be a pool because when the server is idling there are only 3 of them at 0% allocation, then it jumps to 15 at 100%. Then my response times go down the pooper.Seems like I might just be tapping the pool out. I'd like run some bencmarks with more threads in the pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out. Its not a pool of threads. In the jboss-messaging.sar/remoting-bisocket.xml file that defines the remoting connector for Jboss Messaging, you see a couple of values mainly clientMaxPool, maxPoolSize, numAcceptThreads.

In remoting, when a socket is established threads are created to monitor that socket up to the value of "numAcceptThreads". All this thread does is read data from the socket and hand it off to a thread in the client pool(governed by maxPoolSize).

The threads called workerThread#[] refer to the accept threads. The reason that I see more when I create more producers is because for the bisocket transport for Jboss Messaging there apparently are three sockets created. Initially there are 3, but when I create 5 producers that number is increased to 15(or 5*3 for those not mathematically inclined :)). The reason they are 100% allocated is because when I am sending all those messages the threads read from the socket, hand off to Server Thread, go back to reading from the socket(where this is always data)

So the short answer is there is no pool to govern these threads. You can have more than 1 accept thread, but It would almost never make sense. This because its job is so minimal read the data, hand it off, read the data... So have more threads would just add synchronization overhead.

Answer (score -1):

This is from http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html; hope it helps.

When a Swing program needs to execute a long-running task, it usually uses one of the worker threads, also known as the background threads. Each task running on a worker thread is represented by an instance of javax.swing.SwingWorker. SwingWorker itself is an abstract class; you must define a subclass in order to create a SwingWorker object; anonymous inner classes are often useful for creating very simple SwingWorker objects.

Comment: Thats definitely different. See answer below.